# PrimesFaces - Render a panelGroup after onChange

Tags: events, primefaces, selecteditem

I have a `selectOneMenu` with two items  and a `panelGroup`.
When item 1 is selected I want to show the panelGroup and when item 2 is selected hide it.

I try to do it with the `onchange` event but I don't know how show/hide the panelGroup. Maybe using the panelGroup ID ?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{myBean.list}" onchange="???" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1" itemValue="Item 1" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2" itemValue="Item 2" />  
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

the change="" will either give u access to a EL Listener or a javascript, which has no update component to it. You're best off adding a ajax call inside the selectOneMenu.

e.g.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{myBean.list}">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1" itemValue="Item 1" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2" itemValue="Item 2" />
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="myPanelGroup" />
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup" rendered="#{myBean.list == '1'">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

(you need to have rendered on it to ensure it's only shown if your value is 1 (not 2 etc). Although this is the AJAX solution, you could do it using jQuery by binding a change listener to the selectOneMnu 'list' - on change, run your javascript and show/hide the panelgroup div (means u dont need the rendered etc)..

Example:

```
$("#list").change(function(event){
   //get value here and show/hide div using javascript/css what ever you prefer
});
```

Comment: Your post was useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<p:remoteCommand>` tag to update you form. And use rendered to show/hide your panel.

see below code and it is working on my side and much easier.

```
  <p:remoteCommand id="remotecommand" name="updatePanel"
         update="@form"></p:remoteCommand>
<p:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{myBean.list}" onchange="updatePanel()" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1" itemValue="Item 1" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2" itemValue="Item 2" />  
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup" rendered="#{myBean.list eq 'Item 1'}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

When the value of list is `Item 1` on that time show the panel otherwise it is hide

Answer (score 0):

Rendering content on demand is a common practice in jsf. You should also rethink the use of a two choices `selectOneMenu`. You have to wrap the content in a `panelGroup` element and set the inner element to be rendered like this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cboOverview" value="#{ctrlBean.bValue}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="outputOverviewWrapper" />
</p:inputSwitch>
<h:panelGroup id="outputOverviewWrapper">
    <h:panelGroup id="toggleOverview" rendered="#{!ctrlBean.bValue}">
...
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If you want to stick with the `selectOneMenu` you should also use a `valueChangeListener` to set the rendering attribute properly.

Reference is [here](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichIsByItselfConditionallyRendered).